# How to dcast a csv file under r

Tags: r

I have four column and I want dcast on column "Variable". How I can do that.

id| Date | Variable |Value

Comment: Please provide a part of your data using `dput()` to let the users understand your problem.

Comment: `dcast(dat, id~Variable)`. You have to give sample data and the output that you'd expect

Comment: As another said, please provide `dput` of your code. Here is a guide: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg